# Format in Angularjs /Date(-226612800000)/

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The information comes to me through a service which arrives with a negative sign and I must format dd/MM/yyyy

real date = 27/10/1962

```
var date = "/Date(-226612800000)/";     //This is the date that arrives for the service

$scope.Date = new Date(parseInt(date.match(/\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//)[1]));

alert($scope.Date);
```

the negative sign is causing me trouble
I have to work everything inside the AngularJS controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-` character to the matcher:

```js
var date = "/Date(-226612800000)/";     //This is the date that arrives for the service

var date2 = new Date(parseInt(date.match(/\/Date\(([-0-9]*)\)\//)[1]));

console.log(date2);
```